# Comparing two strings in if else

Tags: r, data-analysis

i have three columns in a data frame

```
openratelabels clickratelabels recomendation
good              good            ----
good              bad             ----
bad               good            ----
bad               bad             ----
```

i am trying to compare `openratelabels and clickratelabels`  to suggest a `recommendation`
recommendations for above cases would be anything ie., like text we provide.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

    if(df$OpenRateLabels[i]=="good" & df$ClickRateLabels[i]=="good"){
      df$Recommendation="performing good"}

    else if(df$OpenRateLabels[i]=="good" & df$ClickRateLabels[i]=="bad"){
     df$Recommendation="check creative"}
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error in if (df$OpenRateLabels[i] == "good" & df$ClickRateLabels[i] ==
>   :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: you probably have missing value(s) somewhere in `df$OpenRateLabels` or `df$ClickRateLabels`

Comment: yes i do have missing values in `df$ClickRateLabels` what do i do now ?

Comment: you decide what the `if` is supposed to do when it finds a missing value and, mostly, capture the NA with `is.na` to get a `TRUE/FALSE` to fulfull `if` needs

Comment: Cath can you eloborate your comment.i suppose to return a zero/no analysis done when encountered these NA values.